# angularJs navigation's from ng-route to ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS, and I am a little confused of how I can use angularjs `ui-router` in the following scenario:

It consists of two sections. The first section is the Homepage with its login and sign up views, and the second section is the Dashboard (after a successful login).

- When I logged in success need to navigate from login form to "Home page".
- When I tapped a registration button I need to navigate to "Registration page" from  login page
- Similarly I also need a "forgot password" screen

My current router is below. How can I do this functionality? (Please help with some HTML code and related controllers)

#### app.js:

```
'use strict';
    //Define Routing for app
    angular.module('myApp', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'register.html',
            controller: 'RegisterController'
          })
        .when('/forgotPassword', {
            templateUrl: 'forgotpassword.html',
            controller: 'forgotController'
          })
       .when('/home', {
           templateUrl: 'views/dashBoard.html',
           controller: 'dashBordController'
        })
        .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/login'
        });

    }]);
});
```

Comment: please post more code i am begginer for development(please post html and controllers code also)

Comment: Wait a second.. you mention UI-Router in your question, but the code sample is using ngRouter instead. Is the former just and error or do you really plan to switch to UI-Router?

Comment: yes @SPArchaeologist

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly*, nobody will design a website with your requirements / functionalities for you. `stackoverflow` is for specific problems, your questions is too broad, more about it - [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But to help you with a conversion from `ngRoute` to `ui.router` I can describe what the syntax should look like so you can adopt it for your website.

---

#### Converting to `ui.router`

Your config doesn't change that much. you need to replace `.when` with `.state`, use the right providers, and have the right syntax. Here is an example with just few states:

```js
app.config(config);
/* your preferred way of injecting */
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.
  state("HomepageState", {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: 'views/dashBoard.html',
    controller: 'dashBordController'
  }).
  state("RegisterState", {
    url: "/register",
    templateUrl: 'register.html',
    controller: 'RegisterController'
  })
  /*
    more can be added here...
  */
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
}
```

---

#### Navigation

You should be using states for navigation at all times. So replace `href="url"` with `ui-sref="state"`. Here are some examples of anchor links:

```
<a ui-sref="HomepageState">Home page</a>
<a ui-sref="RegisterState">Register</a>
```

Don't forget to replace your `ng-view` with `ui-view`. (For older browser support it's better to have `<div ui-view></div>` instead of `<ui-view></ui-view>`)

---

#### Redirection

After filling in a login form, the user will press something like:

```
<button ng-click="login()">Sign in</button>
```

which will call a function `login()` that will validate / verify if the user can be logged in. (You can also have `<form ng-submit="login()">` with `<button type="submit">...`) Then, if everything is fine and the user got his session / cookie, you can have a redirection to another page with:

```
$state.go("HomepageState");
```

(Don't forget to inject `$state` into your controller)

---

#### Advanced navigations

In the future if you have user profiles that are listed by their index. Your routing can be improved with `$stateParams`. Their job is to check any additional parameters in the URL. For example: a URL: `/profile/721` can have a state with `url:"/profile/:id"`. Then you can extract that id with `$stateParams.id` and use it in your controllers. And your redirection would look like:

```
$state.go("ProfileState", { "id": 721});
```